# how to separate mesh with armature

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, armature, bones

I'm trying to separate a mesh with armature animation into two by selecting vertices and press P in edit mode. But the separate mesh is all messed up and does not animate accordingly.

Is there any better and cleaner way to achieve that?

Comment: please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: In object mode Alt + P on your mesh or go to Object  > Parent > Clear Parent.

Answer (score 0):

I got it after few tries. Do as the following:

1. Select your object and goto Edit Mode.
2. Select vertices or faces you want to split.
3. Press P and select "By Selection".

The mesh messed up in my case is due to changing action after splitting mesh into 2 objects. Strangely, if you change action while selecting a 3D object, the mesh will go hay-wired. To solve that, be sure you select armature/bones when changing action.